# Where can I get dark blue Techelet for my tzizit and talit?

Tags: product-recommendation, tzitzis, color, techeles

I want to buy some techelet and white tzizit.  I want the techelet to match the color in this picture and to be made by [Ptil Tekhelet](http://www.tekhelet.com/) foundation. However, when I try to contact them on their website I get no response. (I've tried 3 times now)

[image: ancient techelet]

Does anyone know where in Northern Israel I can buy this, or a better way to contact the company?

Most improtantly, I want the techelet to be this color, and not the lighter blue that many people buy.  Because this fabric is from Masada during the 1st centruy and to me, leaves all doubt as to what color techelet is supposed to be. (it hasn't changed color in 1900 years)

Comment: Do you really think every batch of Techelet they made back then came out the same shade of blue?

Comment: Exact same shade? Obviously not.  But this isn't the only source for a darker rather than lighter color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to ever get a hold of them.  My best bet was to go to Jeruselem and buy them from the many stores there.  I was able to find some dark threads, but none as dark as this picture.

Answer (score 5):

They are slow to answer their email and sometimes hard to reach by phone. Ptil Tekhelet makes batches periodically and every batch comes out a slightly different shade of techeles. I don't think your scrap of fabric is such solid proof. Dyeing results vary, and just as the shade of techeles you get nowadays from Ptil Tehkelet varies from one batch to the other, so too it must have been two millenia ago. Your scrap of fabric might be on the lighter or darker end of the spectrum of techeles. BTW, I sell Ptil Tekhelet tzitzit strings, but that won't help you much since I send all my orders by mail.

Comment: Thanks Ben.  Do you sell in Israel, do you take shekels?

Comment: Ben is based in Israel, his website shows that he takes shekalim

Answer (score 3):

If you want darker shades, according to my experience, you should try the niputz lishma strings [Ptil Techelet](https://shop.tekhelet.com/collections/strings) or [the Chabura](https://techeiles-shop.com/). In general, the Chabura ones are darker than Ptil techelet even if not niputz lishma, I have nipputz lishma from the Chabura which closely resemble the hue of that fragment published by Zohar Amar. Both are available at different online sites including their own websites or [dealers](https://tzitzit.tallit-shop.com/).

Answer (score 1):

as a matter of fact, Ptil's techelet is night light-blue at all, it maches the pic you posted quite well!

Comment: ari, Welcome to Judaism.SE, and thanks very much for contributing this information! Linking to or uploading a photo would make your answer much more valuable. Also, please consider registering your account, so that the site can tell its you no matter what computer you come in from.

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully contacted Ptil Tekhelet in the past. If I recall correctly, it did take some time to get email responses. Perhaps you should try calling on the phone. Their number is listed on the website.

Comment: I tried calling the number, and it seemed as if its not in use. Got a wierd sound, not sure what it means.  :(

Comment: @avi Are you sure the "weird sound" wasn't the Israeli telephone tone that's used instead of the "ring" that we are familiar with here in America?

Comment: Yes, I've been in Israel for quite some time now :)  It was more of a 'this line is disconnected' sound. Or its busy and the mailbox is full, or the mail box is full and hasn't been answered in the last 3 phone calls.